# Javascript: Creating an object constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have an object constructor, and I defined a method to setting new values to  the object properties using a json-object as input parameter, *my solution is working*, but I have a doubt on is there a best way to do it?

Any answer using **OOP** will be appreciated.

---

Here is my code:

```
//Object constructor
function searchOption(o) {
   o = o || {};
   this.Word = o.Word || "";
   this.SubCategories = o.SubCategories || [];
   this.Page = o.Page || 1;
   this.Sort = o.Sort || "desc";
   this.ItemsView = o.ItemsView || 18;
   //Method to set new values, preserving untouched properties
   this.set = function (x) { $.extend(this, x); };
}

(function() {
    var search = new searchOption({ Word:"canela", ItemsView:6 });
    console.log(search);
    search.set({ Word:"VIAJE", Page:3, Sort:"asc" });
    console.log(search);
})();
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `this.set = function (x) { searchOption($.extend(this, x)); };`; rather, add `set` to searchOption's prototype.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for [a code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$.extend()` extends the first passed object you even do not need to call constructor function once again in your `set` method

```
searchOption.prototype.set = function(x) {
    $.extend(this, x);
};
```

Fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/eHodoqA/1/edit

**NOTE:**

If you want `SubCategories` to be merged as well - pass `true` as first parameter to `$.extend` that will trigger deep clone (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN)

Comment: See my answer for more substantive improvements, if you are interested.

Answer (score 4):

I would remove `this.set` method from the constructor and use `prototype` instead.

```
//Object constructor
function searchOption(o) {
   o = o || {};
   this.Word = o.Word || "";
   this.SubCategories = o.SubCategories || [];
   this.Page = o.Page || 1;
   this.Sort = o.Sort || "desc";
   this.ItemsView = o.ItemsView || 18;
}

//Method to set new values, preserving the untouched properties
searchOption.prototype.set = function(x) {
    searchOption($.extend(this, x));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Guilherme Sehn, why the prototype will be a better approach instead of defining the method inside the constructor?

Comment: @jherax.corp If you define function inside constructor, you will have new instance of function for each instance of object created using this constructor. In case you use `prototype` function will be shared for all objects created using constructor

Comment: Thanks @Vadim, having shared methods is a best way to do it :)

Comment: See my answer for more substantive improvements, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way in terms of memory consumption since you could share your default values between instances through the `prototype`. The same also apply to functions.

You could implement this new design by using a helper function that copies over the desired members only if they aren't `undefined` or differ from the default values.

Also, as a convention constructor functions starts with an uppercase letter and properties are usually lowerCamelCased. These naming conventions are widely used and I strongly advise you to follow them.

The design that follows is shown for learning purposes and is **not necessary** unless you plan to have a lot of `SearchOption` instances.

```
function applyConfig(obj, config, props) {
    var i = 0,
        len = props.length,
        k, v;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (
            config.hasOwnProperty(k = props[i]) && typeof (v = config[k]) !== 'undefined' //ingore undefined values
            //let default values be shared between instances
            && v !== obj[k]
        ) {
            obj[k] = v;
        }
    }
}

function SearchOption(config) {

    config = config || {};

    //handle all immutable values
    applyConfig(this, config, ['word', 'page', 'sort', 'itemsView']);

    this.subCategories = config.subCategories || [];
}


SearchOption.prototype = {
    constructor: SearchOption,
    //keeping default values on the prototype is memory efficient
    //since they get shared between instances, however we should only use
    //this approach for immutable values.
    word: '',
    page: 1,
    sort: 'desc',
    itemsView: 18,
    //it's better to have functions on the prototype too
    set: function (values) {
        //not sure why you were doing searchOptions(...)? It looks very wrong
        //since the function will get executed in the global object's context (window)

        //note that with the following, we will shadow any default prototype
        //values, unlike when we called the constructor.
        $.extend(this, values);
    }
};

var so1 = new SearchOption(), //share same word
    so2 = new SearchOption(), //share same word
    so3 = new SearchOption({
        word: 'test'
    });

console.log('so1:', so1.word, 'so2:', so2.word, 'so3:', so3.word);

console.log(so1);
```